# Cleaning up DataFrame output | Selenium | Python

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium

I've got a script set up to loop through a group of URLs. The script runs fine, but I can't figure out how to tweak things to produce a cleaner CSV output.

I'll take any suggestions I can to minimize the time needed to clean up the formatting, delete excel cells, and the like.

*Note: The way I'm scraping the volume text has been the only way I've figured out how to get what I need. Hopefully, we can find a good solution for improving the final output without compromising this part of the script.*

**Here's my script:**

```
group_url = [
'https://www.example.com',
'https://www.example2.com',
'https://www.example3.com',
'https://www.example4.com',
]

data = []

for group in group_url:
    driver.get(group)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div')))
    time.sleep(3)

    kws = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".css-hijzdp-base")
    counter = 1
    for kw in kws:
        if counter <= 5:
            try:
                data.append({
                    "Keyword": kw.text
                })
                counter = counter + 1
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass

    urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".css-a5m6co-text.css-p8ym46-fontFamily.css-11397xj-fontSize.css-18j1nfb-display")
    count = 1
    for url in urls:
        if count <= 5:
            try:
                data.append({
                    "URL": url.text
                })
                count = count + 1
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass

    try:
        vol1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        data.append({
            "Volume1": vol1.text
        })
    try:
        vol2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        data.append({
            "Volume2": vol2.text
        })
    try:
        vol3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        data.append({
            "Volume3": vol3.text
        })
    try:
        vol4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        data.append({
            "Volume4": vol4.text
        })
    try:
        vol5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        data.append({
            "Volume5": vol5.text
        })

driver.close()
print(data)
#print to csv
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('testOutput 11_11_21.csv')
```

**Here is a screenshot of the final output:**
[image: Final Output Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You're appending every row item independently to `data`. Collect them first in a dictionary within the for loop, then append the dictionary to the list `data`:

```
group_url = [
'https://www.example.com',
'https://www.example2.com',
'https://www.example3.com',
'https://www.example4.com',
]

data = []

for group in group_url:
    tmp_dict = {}
    
    driver.get(group)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div')))
    time.sleep(3)

    kws = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".css-hijzdp-base")
    counter = 1
    keywords = []
    for kw in kws:
        if counter <= 5:
            try:
                keywords.append(kw.text)
                counter = counter + 1
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
    tmp_dict["Keyword"] = keywords    
    urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".css-a5m6co-text.css-p8ym46-fontFamily.css-11397xj-fontSize.css-18j1nfb-display")
    count = 1
    urls_results = []
    for url in urls:
        if count <= 5:
            try:
                urls_results.append(url.text)
                count = count + 1
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
    tmp_dict["URL"] = urls_results

    try:
        vol1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        tmp_dict["Volume1"]= vol1.text
    try:
        vol2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        tmp_dict["Volume2"]= vol2.text
    try:
        vol3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        tmp_dict["Volume3"]= vol3.text
    try:
        vol4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        tmp_dict["Volume4"]= vol4.text
    try:
        vol5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]/div')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        tmp_dict["Volume5"]= vol5.text
    data.append(tmp_dict)
        
driver.close()
print(data)
#print to csv
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('testOutput 11_11_21.csv')
```

Comment: You are 100% correct @RJ,  it certainly cleans things up, but now it doesn't seem to be looping properly. I did a test just on the "kw" section, but it's just iterating over the same first keyword five times. Any idea why it would be adjusting the loop?

Comment: I didn't alter anything in the code but changing `data.append` to inserting the data in the tmp dict. So likely the loop issue has a different cause. Can't debug it myself without the urls.

Comment: Is it possible `data.append(tmp_dict)` just needs an indentation adjustment?

Comment: No, the indentation is fine. What is the error message?

Comment: There's no error message, just a looping issue now. Maybe I should ask a new question?

Comment: You could do that, but we'd still not be able to debug the code without the url.

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't help. The URLs I'm accessing require a login.

Comment: I made some improvements in the urls section, which now stores the urls as a list. It will probably not solve the 'looping issue'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239135/discussion-between-micadeli-and-rj-adriaansen).